# Jmeter - Java.Net.SocketException

Tags: jmeter, socketexception

I am running a Jmeter script on a web-application which is hosted on IIS and using ADFS authentication mechanism.
For each request in Jmeter,it fails due to "Java.Net.SocketException ".

**What I have done is:**
Used HTTP Authentication manager to provide credentials for each user from CSV data config element.But seems like still Jmeter is not logging-in.

Followed the documentation of Jmeter HTTP authorization manager but it looks like it's not login to the application

**In the Jmeter log files -I see is :**

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor: ntlm authentication scheme selected 
2014/05/22 16:34:22 INFO  - org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector: No credentials available for NTLM <any realm>@DomainName:PortNumber ..
2014/05/22 16:34:31 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: HTTP request retry count = 1 
2014/05/22 16:34:31 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Setting up HTTPS TrustAll scheme 
2014/05/22 16:34:32 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$4: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset 
2014/05/22 16:34:32 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$4: Retrying request 
2014/05/22 16:34:32 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$4: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset 
2014/05/22 16:34:32 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$4: Retrying request 
_________________
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor64.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.readResponse(HTTPJavaImpl.java:264)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:520)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1088)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1077)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
```

---

Can above exception occur due to authentication failure ?

Please suggest to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Verify that there is not an opened session with same login and password used in jmeter test it's maybe the reason

Comment: @lmen - Thank-you for the suggestion.. I closed all the opened session with used login and password in Jmeter test..and re-started Jmeter and again executed the same test but I am getting the same error..

Comment: You are welcome, So verify your network connection, also verify that you are accessing to the right url with the write port number. did you use http(s) script recorder to record actions in the browser?

Comment: I will definitely verify the connection ,url and port details and let you know what happens and  No, I have not used HTTP(s) script recorder to record actions in the browser .@lmen - Thank-you for your quick reply and help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some days of troubleshooting
- I found that each of my requests was failing because of login failure.

So when Jmeter login fails at that time it does not get Security token in response  and for every request security token is sent as a cookie.

So When that cookie is empty at that time server asks for credentials and Jmeter request was failing because of `Java.Net.SocketException`.

The example security token is -

**Cookie Data:**

```
Token=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; .ASPXAUTH=E2EF9B7E3395B09FE1988C1A20BA2DD5A395FF15E40C5BA0C078038D799CC8A234602A4788565EBB30804E91154713FBB8E935FF1868871697C6B9681F8D181F2104BDDDAF645A87307FE7B6434D2F749BA6684F49E301FDA40703D0C8B4CAFBE2837D1BB84EE7A0DA66ABA5D61D074EBC985CBA6C5F3E94053878E4AD942393A71F5563259F4A584C3789F523174B3B
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have improper configuration of your [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)

As per [AD FS 2.0: How to Change the Local Authentication Type](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1600.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-change-the-local-authentication-type.aspx) ADFS can be configured to support following authentication types:

1. Integrated Windows authentication (IWA) - NTLM or Kerberos
2. Forms-based authentication (FBA)
3. Transport layer security client authentication
4. Basic authentication

Points 1 and 4 can be handled via HTTP Authorization Manager. See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) guide for how-to.

Point 2 can be handled via correlation (i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor))

Point 3 I believe it can be handled via [Keystore Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration)